# Iocomp Winforms Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, controls

I am planning on using Iocomp plot for very high speed plotting functions in my WPF application. The issue is that Iocomp components are purely winforms based and I have not been able to integrate it at all with WPF. Any pointers on the same would be great.

Comment: Use the WindowsFormsHost class, it was made to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hans. When trying out the addition of Plot control to WindowsFormsHost in VS2010, I was getting compiling issues with Iocomp.Class assembly. On a whim I tried the same in VS2008 and did not face the issue. I am checking to see if I can implement the complete control functionality (currently I have just added a plot programatically) into the WindowsFormsHost. Will Post the results

Comment: Figured out a solution to the issue. In Visual studio 2010 when I set the Framework to .Net 4 it works when it is set to .Net 4 (client profile) it does not. Iocomp Plot may be using some assemblies which are not supported in client profile.